# Unable to drag ports from expression to joiner transformation

Tags: informatica

The problem occurs when I try to drag ports from expression transformation to joiner transformation. Same problem in same mapping with an aggregator transformation.

What can be wrong?

Comment: A error message is shown at the bottom of the PowerCenter Designer window when you try to make an invalid connection. What does it say?

Comment: linking lines are not visible only ports are copied to joiner transformation.

Comment: But what message is shown at the bottom the moment you try to connect the transformations?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution here:
  The problem is we have to check the sorted input checkbox from the joiner    transformation in properties tab.
it will help you to solve this problem.

Comment: In case of self-join (joinig data that originate from same upstream transformation). Just make sure the data is actually sorted. Otherwise the execution will fail.